# How to use multiple where conditions during pandas merge

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes like as shown below

```
op1 = pd.DataFrame({
   'subject_id':[1,1,1,1,1,1],
   'date' : ['1/1/2017','1/2/2017','1/3/2017','1/4/2017','1/5/2017','1/6/2017'],
    'val' :[5,10,5,16,26,6]
 })

op2 = pd.DataFrame({
      'subject_id':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
      'date' : ['1/1/2017','1/2/2017','1/3/2017','1/4/2017','1/5/2017','1/6/2017','1/7/2017'],
      'val' :[5,1,15,6,2,6,8]
  })
```

I would like to copy records from `op2` (which aren't present in `op1`) and put it in final dataframe `d`. So `NaNs` for the `val` records in `op1` are filled by `val` from `op2` records. So I would like to merge records `where val is NaN`. This is what I tried but it doesn't work

```
d = op1.merge(op2, on = ['subject_id','date'],how='outer')
d[d['val_x'].isna()]['val_x'] = d['val_y']
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Comment: Both the answers below were really good. Based on my limited proficiency with Python, I mark answer which is easy and short. I don't really know the intricacies of both the answers. So I can mark only one. unless authors themselves wish to recommend one over another. I liked both answers. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can also use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) by setting `['subject_id','date']` as index:

```
(op1.set_index(['subject_id','date'])
  .combine_first(op2.set_index(['subject_id','date'])).reset_index())
```

---

```
   subject_id      date   val
0           1  1/1/2017   5.0
1           1  1/2/2017  10.0
2           1  1/3/2017   5.0
3           1  1/4/2017  16.0
4           1  1/5/2017  26.0
5           1  1/6/2017   6.0
6           1  1/7/2017   8.0
```

Comment: For combine_first, does the dataframes have to be in same shape? I mean equal number of rows?

Comment: If it has to replace `NaN`, then it has to look for same row index value in next dataframe

Comment: @SSMK no, so whatever index is missing in df2, it brings to df1 , so we are setting the `['subject_id','date']` as index for the match :) and then reset index to bring to original form

Comment: Sure. was reading that. It just doesn't really do anything. Just avoid duplicates values (retain only first occurrence) and brings the new ones from `op2` dataframe as well. Am I right?

Comment: it matches the index of the 2 dataframes and combine the non matching index values from df2 to df1, also if matching index in df1 has NaN, it brings the value from the same index from df2 to df1 @SSMK

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198810/discussion-between-ssmk-and-anky-91).

Answer (score 3):

Add parameter `suffixes` and then repalce missing values with `fillna` and `pop` for extract column:

```
d = op1.merge(op2, on = ['subject_id','date'],how='outer', suffixes=('','_'))
d['val'] = d['val'].fillna(d.pop('val_'))

print (d)
   subject_id      date   val
0           1  1/1/2017   5.0
1           1  1/2/2017  10.0
2           1  1/3/2017   5.0
3           1  1/4/2017  16.0
4           1  1/5/2017  26.0
5           1  1/6/2017   6.0
6           1  1/7/2017   8.0
```

In your solution is possible use:

```
d.loc[d['val'].isna(), 'val'] = d['val_']
```